# Author's GPG subkey has expired, what can I do?

Tags: package-management, encryption, gpg, software-updates, pgp

I am trying to download an update for a piece of software, and my package manager says that the key is invalid and thus warns me.

`W: Failed to fetch https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/dists/buster/InRelease  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 74A941BA219EC810 deb.torproject.org archive signing key`

Then the output after listing the key in GPG.

```
pub   rsa2048/0xEE8CBC9E886DDD89 2009-09-04 [SC] [expires: 2022-08-05]
      Key fingerprint = A3C4 F0F9 79CA A22C DBA8  F512 EE8C BC9E 886D DD89
uid                   [ unknown] deb.torproject.org archive signing key
sub   rsa2048/0x74A941BA219EC810 2009-09-04 [S] [expires: 2020-11-23]
      Key fingerprint = 2265 EB4C B2BF 88D9 00AE  8D1B 74A9 41BA 219E C810
```

As you can see, the subkey has expired recent to writing this post.

I went to the developer's website and the signing key is unchanged. How do I continue the software update without skipping the signing process?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [2019.www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en](https://2019.www.torproject.org/docs/debian.html.en), you can run these commands to add the key to the trusted apt keys, I only added `sudo`:

```
curl https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc | gpg --import
gpg --export A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89 | sudo apt-key add -
```

After that `sudo apt-key list` (or `gpg --list-keys`) should list the updated key:

```
pub   rsa2048 2009-09-04 [SC] [expires: 2024-11-17]
      A3C4 F0F9 79CA A22C DBA8  F512 EE8C BC9E 886D DD89
uid           [ unknown] deb.torproject.org archive signing key
sub   rsa2048 2009-09-04 [S] [expires: 2022-06-11]
```

Now you can install the keyring package if you wish to keep the key current:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install deb.torproject.org-keyring
```

The `deb.torproject.org-keyring` package contains the current version of the archive signing key (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/deb.torproject.org-keyring.gpg) to validate the authenticity of tor packages.

If you install the package, you'll automatically update the key next time you run `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade` whenever there is an updated version of the key available (assuming the currently installed key is not expired to fetch the package via apt).

Comment: This sort of worked on a RaspberryPi but I am unsure what it actually does. Maybe somebody can elaborate what key we are importing and why it solves the problem. Also, it would be interesting to know, what `org-keyring` does or what "keeping the key current" means. Thanks! ("sort of worked" because I got `N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-armhf/Packages' as repository 'https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org buster InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'armhf'` but I was able to upgrade other packages.)

Comment: The `deb.torproject.org-keyring` package contains the current version of the archive signing key (`/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/deb.torproject.org-keyring.gpg`, the key you just manually imported) to validate the authenticity of tor packages.
If you install the package, you'll automatically update the key next time you run `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade` whenever there is an updated version of the key available (assuming the currently installed key is not expired to fetch the package via apt).

Comment: Thanks! I added your comment to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me this worked:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 74A941BA219EC810
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that [brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You may want to add a note _why_ you think this approach will solve the OPs problem.